# AttributeError: 'RandomForestClassifier' object has no attribute 'fit_transform'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am getting an error

> AttributeError: 'RandomForestClassifier' object has no attribute 'fit_transform'

However, there is a method named fit_transform(X,y) in sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier. [This can be seen here](http://ogrisel.github.io/scikit-learn.org/sklearn-tutorial/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html)
I don't understand why I am getting this error and how do I resolve it. 
Here is the code snippet-

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import pickle
import sys
import numpy as np

X1=np.array(pickle.load(open('X2g_train.p','rb')))
X2=np.array(pickle.load(open('X3g_train.p','rb')))
X3=np.array(pickle.load(open('X4g_train.p','rb')))
X4=np.array(pickle.load(open('Xhead_train.p','rb')))

X=np.hstack((X2,X1,X3,X4))
y = np.array(pickle.load(open('y.p','rb')))
rf=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=200)
Xr=rf.fit_transform(X,y)
```

Comment: The documentation you are using is for a very old version of scikit. Seems like you dont have that version installed.

Answer (score 3):

There's no such method in the [scikit-learn API documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier)

To train your model and get predictions, you need to do like this

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier()

# train the model
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# get predictions
predictions = rf.predict(X_test)
```